# Most efficient way of finding an item at a certain index in a List<>, modifying the item and then updating the List<>?

Tags: c#, collections

Take `List<Car>`. Each `Car` has a unique index identifying it, say `RegNumber` and then another property describing it - say `Color` for example.

I want to

1. check if the collection has a car with RegNumber 5
2. if it does, change the color
3. if it doesn't, add a new item for that car
4. save the list

This is the way I am currently doing it and I'm asking if there is a better, more efficient way of doing this?

```
Car car = CarsForSale.Find(c => c.RegNumber == 5);

if (car != null)
{
   foreach (Car car in CarsForSale)
   {
      if (car.RegNumber == 5)
      {
         car.Color = "Red";
         break;
      }
   }
}
else
{
   CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}

Save(CarsForSale);
```

***EDIT***
There are not multiple cars with the same reg - the RegNumber is unique as stated in the question.

This was really just a total dumb@ss moment here anyway that a code review would have spotted. Thanks for all the replies and for not mocking my clearly stoopid question. Of course the item/element returned from the collection is a reference so there is absolutely no need to iterate through the list again...time to go bang my head against a wall I think.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, tag it as such.

Comment: Efficient as in...? Fast, low memory print, short execution path, minimal code?

Comment: why are you iterating over all cars in this foreach loop? You already have the car with reg number == 5, no?

Comment: You do not to modify the List<>. The Cars in the List<> are just references. If you modify the Car, then the change is also visible to the List<>.

Comment: @Havard - No it's not homework so it's not marked as so. The class names are just examples for the purpose of the code here.

Comment: @Sani - Efficient as in the best approach that will get me the result with the minimum amount of code without unnecessary iteration of the collection.

Comment: @Peter Kelly: If the `RegNumber` is indeed unique, you should really consider using a `Dictionary<int, Car>` instead of a `List<Car>`, as I suggested in my answer. This will make finding your car O(1) vs. O(N). (Then again, if your collection consists of only a handful of cars, never mind.)

Comment: @Dan Tao: A Dictionary<int, Car> where the int key represents the reg number? So the value part of the KeyValue pair, Car, also has the reg number as one of its properties - doesn't seem right to me?

Comment: @Peter Kelly: If it doesn't feel right to you, there's nothing I can really do about that. But it is totally an appropriate storage mechanism for lookup scenarios such as this one. Your `Values` property would consist of your `Car` objects; your `Keys` property would consist of your `RegNumber` values. Actually, it is very rare (in my experience) for a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to be keyed on some value that is *not* a property of `TValue` objects. Looking up a `TValue` in the dictionary based on one of its properties: that's the whole idea.

Comment: @Dan Tao: Okay, thanks. I always have assumed built-in types would have been the most common usage e.g. Dictionary<int, string>. I've always seen examples using that rather than a custom type with a property of TValue as the TKey. Maybe I've been looking at the wrong examples!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first off you don't need your test for `car.RegNumber == 5` in the loop - you've already found the first car that match this criterion from your statement:

```
Car car = CarsForSale.Find(c => c.RegNumber == 5);
```

In fact your whole loop is redundant, you can just have:

```
if (car != null)
{
    car.Color = "Red";
}
else
{
    CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}
```

Unless you want to find all cars that have `RegNumber` equal to 5, in which case your first line is incorrect as that will only find the first car that matches the criteria. To find all the cars you want something along these lines:

```
var cars = CarsForSale.Where(c => c.RegNumber == 5);

foreach (Car car in cars)
{
    car.Color = "Red";
}

if (!car.Any())
{
    CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}
```

With your original code the compiler should have warned you that the redefinition of `car` in the loop would hide the original definition (the one I've quoted).

Comment: I don't think that's a Linq statement.

Comment: car.Count() == 0 is horrible way to test for no elements because if collection is not an ICollection<T> it will have to loop through all elements. Use !car.Any() instead which just checks the first elements existence.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you re-iterating through the list when you already have a result?

This will achieve the same outcome:

```
Car car = CarsForSale.Find(c => c.RegNumber == 5);
if (car != null)
{
   car.Color = "Red";
}
else
{
   CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}
Save(CarsForSale);
```

The result from the `Find` method of `CarsForSale`, if it returns a result, will be a reference type, which means any changes to `car` will change the item in `CarsForSale` as well. I'm guessing you thought that the result from `Find` would be disconnected from the actual item in `CarsForSale`, hence the unnecessary foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the car you're looking for from the LINQ statement, there's no need to loop back through the collection to find the match:

```
Car car = CarsForSale.Where(c => c.RegNumber == 5).FirstOrDefault();

if(car != null)
{
    car.Color = "Red";
}
else
{
    CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}

Save(CarsForSale);
```

Or if there are going to be multiple Cars with the same RegNumber:

```
var cars = CarsForSale.Where(c => c.RegNumber == 5);

if(cars.Any())
{
    foreach(Car car in cars)
        car.Color = "Red";
}
else
{
    CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}

Save(CarsForSale);
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() will take the first match only. Find() will do the same thing.

Comment: Don't use Where followed by FirstOrDefault. FirstOrDefault has an overload that takes a filter. And anyways if CarsForSale is a List<Car>, using Find is better.

Comment: @Trillian - Even though you can pass a Predicate to FirstOrDefault, I like to keep them separate to clearly state intent and make it easier to modify in the future (even if marginally so). The two get evaluated the same so there's no performance difference. Also, why would List.Find() be any better (especially given the fact that he might need multiple matches)?

Comment: Of course Find won't do if there are multiple matches. But for a single match, it is slightly better than FirstOrDefault because it's provided by the class itself and skips the overhead of using an enumerator. Ok, maybe I'm nitpicking :)

Comment: @Trillian My point was more that Find() (more than likely, I can't check at the moment) uses an enumerator anyway so I still don't see the extra overhead.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

In response to this comment you've left on a couple of other answers:

> What if there are several cars with
> the RegNumber of 5?

If it's possible for multiple cars to have the same `RegNumber`, then calling `Find` is not the right approach. `Find` is just enumerating over the list to find a match; you'd be better off skipping it and keeping your `foreach` loop.

You could, however, make your code more concise by using `Where` instead:

```
var matches = CarsForSale.Where(c => c.RegNumber == 5);
int numMatches = 0;

foreach (Car match in matches )
{
    match.Color = "Red";
    ++numMatches;
}
if (numMatches == 0)
{
   CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}
```

---

### Original answer

That whole `foreach` loop is redundant: you're basically doing the same work you already did by calling `Find`.

So the code can be simplified:

```
Car car = CarsForSale.Find(c => c.RegNumber == 5);

if (car != null)
{
    car.Color = "Red";
}
else
{
   CarsForSale.Add(new Car(5, "Red"));
}
```

That said, if you're looking up cars in your `List<Car>` by `RegNumber`, it would make sense to use a `Dictionary<int, Car>` instead of a `List<Car>`:

```
Car car;
if (CarsForSale.TryGetValue(5, out car))
{
    car.Color = "Red";
}
else
{
    CarsForSale[5] = car = new Car(5, "Red");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So as Dan already mentioned, if you have a unique property you should use it as a key within a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Cause checking if something is within a Dictionary is an O(1) operation, while within a List it is just O(n) in the worst case (and now imagine you have 1 million cars within your list).

```
var carsForSale = new Dictionary<int, Car>();

//Create a car which you like to check
var checkCar = new Car(4, Color.Red);

//Use this approach if you want to change only a few properties
//of an existing item
if (carsForSale.ContainsKey(checkCar.RegNum))
{
    carsForSale[checkCar.RegNum].Color = checkCar.Color;
}
else
{
    carsForSale[4] = checkCar;
}

//If you have to take over ALL property settings, you can also
//forget the old item and take the new one.
//The index operator is smart enough to just add a new one
//or to delete an old and add the new in one step.
carsForSale[checkCar.RegNum] = checkCar;
```

Dummy implementation of the car class:

```
public class Car
{
    public int RegNum { get; private set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Car(int regNum)
        : this(regNum, Color.Empty)
    { }

    public Car(int regNum, Color color)
    {
        RegNum = regNum;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

The *problem* why you are using a Dictionary is, cause you want to explicitly tell what the key is (the RegNum property of your car), but you could also use a [`Hashset<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) if your Car object would correctly implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` but this is a little more complex than you might think. A good explanation can be found in the [Essentials C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321694694) book.

Comment: Thanks Oliver, I take your point (and Dan's) on the Dictionary being more efficient. I hadn't thought of Hashset<T> so I'll look into that too and see if it applies in my case.

Comment: Yes, a HashSet would also work, if two items with the same RegNumber would reveal the same HashCode.